# discord.py rewrite/delete standard help command

Tags: discord.py

I want to make a custom !help command but I have to disable the standard one first. When I do:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
client.remove_command('help')
```

Or

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', help_command=None)
```

It still shows this message:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut9dO.png
Anyone how to delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way of making a help command is by using groups.
Firstly remove the default command;

```py
client.remove_command("help")
```

After that make a help command by using this method:

```py
@client.group(invoke_without_command= True)

async def help(ctx):
    # insert your help command embed or message here
    embed= discord.Embed(title="Help", description="List of commands")
    embed.add_field(name="Moderation", value="!help moderation")
    embed.add_field(name="Misc", value="!help misc")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

You are done with the help command, now when you have to make help for a category or command. You can do it like this:

```py
@help.command()

async def moderation(ctx):
    embed= discord.Embed(title="Moderation", description="List of Moderation commands")
    embed.add_field(name="Commands", value="ban, kick, warn, mute, unban")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Now if user will type, `!help moderation` the above embed/message will be sent.

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution, can you find this on the documentation or something?

Comment: @ChiMC My bad, I forgot to mention documentation. Here it is: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.group

Answer (score 0):

With the recent changes in discord.py-rewrite you do not need to delete the standard help command to create your own help command. To achieve what you want you will need to subclass `HelpCommand` or `MinimalHelpCommand`, then pass it to bot.help_command.

The following code shows the standard way of subclassing `MinimalHelpCommand`:

```
class MyHelpCommand(commands.MinimalHelpCommand):
    def get_command_signature(self, command):
        return '{0.clean_prefix}{1.qualified_name} {1.signature}'.format(self, command)

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self._original_help_command = bot.help_command
        bot.help_command = MyHelpCommand()
        bot.help_command.cog = self

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.bot.help_command = self._original_help_command
```

Following the code above you will get the behaviour that you want to achieve, but if you still want to disable the default help command for any reasons, nowadays you can do it passing `None` to the `help_command` kwarg.

For more info, discord.py documentation:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#help-commands